# Increasing the log length of /var/log/httpd/access_log?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

My apache log seems to have only 3 days worth of records. How can I modify it to retain everything?

I think ideally it should move to another log file name every week or so, in order to give me time to download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this apache instance runs on some sort of Linux server, you would need to look at either /etc/logrotate.conf or /etc/logrotate.d/. The latter is a folder that usually contains files named after the daemons for which they hold logrotation configuration. In the case of Debian based systems, the file name would apache or apache2, on redhat based systems it would be httpd.

Read the man page for logorotate, that should give you enough information to either modify an existing configuration or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're not just seeing the last 3 days logs because the others have been archived by logrotate ? Have a look and see if yo have any access_log.1 .2 or access_log.1.gz .2.gz etc files which will be older ones.

If you don't already have archived logs check `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd` (or `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`) to see how your logs are being rotated. If you have the parameter `rotate` set to `0` then your old logs will be deleted rather than archived. Check the man page for [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) for more information.